# How to implement "Go To Definition" for application elements with leading description?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2017  C#

In writing code, I find it very useful to right-click on a system element and select "Go To Definition". This very neatly shows the element's properties and methods with the leading "..." being nicely expandable to give a full text definition of the immediately following property/method.

How could I duplicate this help function for my own code? In particular, I wish to condense a leading descriptions into "..." prior to the following property/method.

TIA

Example display on "Inkcanvas[metadata]":

[image]

Comment: You mean just this view with no source code, or just the ... part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select `Go To Definition`, Visual Studio will show metadata if it couldn't find the source code. And the expandable "..." only appear in metadata viewer.
To achieve something like this, let's say we have a library containing the following code:

```
namespace Library
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void MyMethod() { }
    }
}
```

1. Add some documentation for it:

```
namespace Library
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Documentation for MyClass
    /// </summary>
    public class MyClass
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Documentation for MyMethod
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter">Parameter decription</param>
        public void MyMethod(int parameter) { }
    }
}
```

2. Then go to `Project Properties` -> `Build` and check `XML documentation file`.
3. Compile the library.
4. In another **solution**, add reference for the compiled `Library`.
5. Write some code using class from `Library`:

```
namespace UseTheLibrary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new MyClass().MyMethod(0);
        }
    }
}
```

6. Now use the `Go To Definition`.
And you can see "..." in the metadata viewer.
[image: Screenshot]
Of course expandable:
[image: Expand]

Comment: May I ask how you achieved that background?

Comment: @FurkanKambay It's a Visual Studio extension called `ClaudialIDE`, here is the [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kbuchi.ClaudiaIDE).

Answer (score 2):

1. The metadata view

   - Since you have the project opened in Visual Studio, `Go to definition` will navigate to the source file for that symbol. If you want just the metadata view, then you can reference the project's DLL in another project (in a solution where you don't have this one opened), and it will show you just the metadata since you can't see the source code as you only have the DLL.
2. The `...` part

   - That part is XML documentation. You can read more at Microsoft Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc